# invalid authentication at bank

Tags: payment-gateway

<Getting this error after the payment through the payment gateway and not getting successful payment. Can anyone suggest what is the issue? Always invalid authentication at bank showing>

Comment: Please specify exactly which API you're using and provide sample code that demonstrates the problem. Without this, we cannot even guess what the problem is.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.